# How to prevent Mathematica from maximum CPU usage?

Tags: performance-tuning, parallelization, hardware

I have a high-demanding Mathematica task that uses Compile and turns on parallelization. While evaluating, it always consumes around 100% of CPU.

Could you please tell me how to reduce the maximal consumption by e.g. ~90%?

I tried to use

```
LaunchKernels[7]
```

(I have 8 logical cores), but the CPU usage did not change.

Comment: This is something you should do on the OS. e.g on windows reduce the process priority from task manager and set the processor affinity.

Comment: @flinty : as far as I see, in Windows it is not possible to adjust the resource usage in a flexible way. It only allows to turn on the efficiency mode, with unknown limitations on the performance.

Comment: @flinty : in addition, I do not see such an option on Windows 10 enterprise.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208/windows-equivalent-of-nice

Comment: `SetSystemOptions[SystemOptions["ParallelOptions"] /. (("ParallelThreadNumber" -> x_) :> ("ParallelThreadNumber" -> threadCount))]`